# Does Message Sampling Processor in WSO2 ESB support reliable messaging

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

In `WSO2ESB` the message sampling processor de-queues the messages from the queue and forward it to a sequence where we can do transformation to the request and send to the back - end. And 
`The main purpose of using MSMP is for archiving guaranteed delivery, or in other words, to archive reliable messaging.` [[Source]](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/01/guaranteed-delivery-with-Message-Store-Message-Processor%20/)

But when we use `Message Sampling Processor` it just forward the message to sequence and the processor doesn't know whether the message successfully delivered to the back end (using `send` | `call` mediator) or  the processor knows this and restore the message in the queue?
I tried this scenario using JMS-Message Store (`WSO2MB`) and what I found is, message get lost when the back end service is down.

Answer (score 1):

Message Sampling processor does not support reliable messaging[1]. For reliable messaging you will have to use Message Forwarding processor[2]

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Message+Sampling+Processor

[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Message+Forwarding+Processor

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, do u have any idea about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390273/sequence-defined-in-the-message-processor-doesnt-receive-the-response